# PHP zip function makes zip but downloads

Tags: php, download, makefile, zip

I have a function, called `zip`, that makes a zip out of a folder. Works perfectly, except that it downloads the zip after making it. I want users to be able to download and make backups on demand. But they are download when they are **made** as well. This is my PHP code:

```
    function zip($source, $destination){
    if (extension_loaded('zip') === true){
        if (file_exists($source) === true){
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            if ($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === true ){
                $source = realpath($source);
                if (is_dir($source) === true){
                    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                    foreach ($files as $file){
                        $file = realpath($file);
                        if (is_dir($file) === true){
                            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
                        }
                        else if (is_file($file) === true){
                            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (is_file($source) === true) {
                    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
                    }
            }
            return $zip->close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
zip("../data", "backup.zip");
```

Does anyone know how to fix my problem? Thanks in advance!

### Note:

The plain-text version is: [here](http://myjacobsplace.com/back.html)

Comment: When does that happen exactly? I see nothing in the code you show that should cause the zip file to be passed through to the browser

Comment: I don't know. I even included a Location header after the call to `zip`.

Comment: And what do you do AFTER sending that Location header? Because if there's no `exit` then the rest of the script will still be executed.

Comment: Yes, there is an `exit` after the location header. The location header just goes to the main page of the tool I am developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem but I was making the zip files differently so I dont know if this will apply. My issue was with Internet Explorer, I would create the zip file when the user clicked a link and in IE it would auto download when it was done but the other browsers would work fine.

I would check for the $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] in my link and I had to add "target=_blank" to it in order to stop IE from auto downloading.

Comment: Wasn't the problem, I fixed the real one, but I think I should at least give the the accept thing. Your the only one who answered anyway. =}